# Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException] Connection timed out

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am unable to send mail from my cakephp 3 website. I tried a simiple testmail.php file, I received the email but when I try the same username and password set on app.php I am getting connection timed out.

```
Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException] Connection timed out
```

This is on 1and1.com. I am able to send mails when setup on localhost.

what could be wrong:

Here is the error.log:

```
2017-08-24 14:05:09 Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException] Connection timed out
Request URL: /contactus/
Referer URL: https://example.com/
Stack Trace:
#0 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php(207): Cake\Network\Socket->connect()
#1 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php(162): Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport->_connect()
#2 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Mailer/Transport/DebugKitTransport.php(79): Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport->send(Object(Cake\Mailer\Email))
#3 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Email.php(1344): DebugKit\Mailer\Transport\DebugKitTransport->send(Object(Cake\Mailer\Email))
#4 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/src/Controller/UsersController.php(335): Cake\Mailer\Email->send()
#5 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/src/Controller/UsersController.php(113): App\Controller\UsersController->_sendVerificationCode(Object(Cake\ORM\Entity))
#6 [internal function]: App\Controller\UsersController->ajaxRegister()
#7 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(435): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(121): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#9 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(95): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\UsersController))
#10 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(83): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#11 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#12 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(62): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#13 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#14 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#15 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#16 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(81): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#17 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#18 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#19 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(90): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#20 /homepages/30/d665828522/htdocs/app/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#21 {main}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please verify your custom EmailTransport configuration and be sure that you use your custom EmailTransport configuration and not the default one?

In App.php EmailTransport configuration should be like this:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 25,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
        'custom' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'A.B.C.D', // Ip of your server
            'port' => XX, // Port that you use: 25 or 465 or 587
            'timeout' => 60,
            'username' => 'MyUsername',
            'password' => 'MyPassword', 

            'client' => null,
            'tls' => true,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
        'debug' => [ 
            'className' => 'Debug',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'A.B.C.D', // Ip of your server
            'port' => XX, // Port that you use: 25 or 465 or 587
            'timeout' => 60,
            'username' => 'MyUsername',
            'password' => 'MyPassword', 

            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
        'gmail' => [
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password_of_test',
            'headers' => array(
              'X-Mailer' => 'PHP'
            ),
            'charset' => 'UTF8',
            'headerCharset' =>  'UTF8',
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            'tls' => null
        ],

    ],
```

And inside your controller send your email like this:

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    use Cake\Mailer\Email;
    /* ... */

    private function sendResetEmail($msg, $user) {

        $email = new Email();
        $email->transport('custom'); // Here we call to ou custom config

        $email->template('YourEmailTemplate');
        $email->emailFormat('both');
        $email->from('noreply@example.com');
        $email->to($user->email, $user->username);
        $email->subject('Reset your password');
        $email->viewVars(['msg' => $msg, 'username' => $user->username]);
        try {
            $email->send();
          } catch(Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("Exception caught with message: " . $e->getMessage().'\n'.$email->smtpError);
          }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The setup I tried on localhost works from correctly when I upload the same to server it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe on your server you have a firewall. if it's a linux, try to ping the server, and if it answer try to connect manually to your smtp server with telnet : "**telnet [adresse or your server] [port, 25/465 or 587]**".  On window you can check the connection with **putty**.

Comment: As I said before there is no firewall issue because testmail.php works fine with SMTP 25/465/587 all are working.